# Create dynamic Page XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I am new to WP8 app dev.

Scenario:

- WP application client and Server
- Application will display content received from server
- Response from server has 2 types : list item page or detail page.

Question:

- When server responses a list, Client app must be create a dynamic list Page with data from server
- When user click an item on list, server may response a list (cont.) or a detail of this item (user dont know list or detail).

Please recommend a solution for this case support Navigation Back pressed? (only create a page using object parameter response from server)

Start page -> List -> List-> List->List-> Detail Page.

or : Start page -> List -> Detail Page.

Comment: your wording seem to suggest you want to parse/render XAML code dynamically during runtime, is this really what you want and/or need? 

Do you know what the underlying data objects are and how to render/display them? If so, make life easy and create a listview page and a detailviiew page, and then decide which of these to show based on some criteria/value from server/user input.

Comment: Keep the same page and use listbox control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is unclear, but I will try to resolve the ambiguity. If the data from the server is just that - data, then you don't need to create XAML dynamically, you should use `LongListSelector` for displaying arbitrary lists of data. This is the case when the amount of data is unspecified, but the structure is the same. See [MSDN link](http://www.google.hr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj244365%28v=vs.105%29.aspx&ei=BEDeUuydBIOZyAPay4GYBQ&usg=AFQjCNEp247OJ7E9_pYaHZNGaygq-FFI3g&sig2=ScsvZkkwv3ou4KG3dPMC0w&bvm=bv.59568121,d.bGQ) for more information.

When you get the details from the server, simply use data binding to fill predefined controls on the page. You can always hide unused controls.

In case that the data that comes from the server *changes* UI in a way that cannot be predetermined e.g. each list looks completely different and details page is also variable, you should create XAML on the fly. Simply create empty pages and in the constructor add controls. For example:

```
// ListPage.xaml
<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel x:Name="panel">
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>

// ListPage.xaml.cs
public ListPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    foreach(var data in somesource)
    {
        if (...)
            panel.Children.Add(new TextBlock());
        else
            panel.Children.Add(new TextBox());
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use like this:

Have 2 pages ,First One for List View and the Second for Details view.
Based on the server responses pass the data to corresponding pages,whichever you want.You are not allowed to create pages dynamically and use them.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't need to create dynamic xaml page. Create three pages 
1. Start Page
2. List Page
3.Detail Page

In list page use a ListBox control and bind listbox with your server data. [Here](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Listbox_handling_in_Windows_Phone) and [enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox%28VS.95%29.aspx) nice explanation about listbox control